# Java Script. Выполнение скрипта при изменении ширины элемента

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! И сразу к вопросу.
Имеется скрипт:

```
<script>
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#left-f, #right-f')).forEach(function(a) {  // селекторы блоков, которые будут фиксироваться. Может быть как один блок, так два и более
var b = null, P = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
function Ascroll() {
if (b == null) {
var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ''), s = '';
for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
  if (Sa[i].indexOf('overflow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('padding') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('border') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('outline') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('box-shadow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('background') == 0) {
    s += Sa[i] + ': ' +Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + '; '
  }
}
b = document.createElement('div');
b.style.cssText = s + ' box-sizing: border-box; width: ' + a.offsetWidth + 'px;';
a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
var l = a.childNodes.length;
for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
  b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
}
a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
a.style.padding = '0';
a.style.border = '0';
}
var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
  R = Math.round(Ra.top + b.getBoundingClientRect().height -     document.querySelector('#top-four').getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 0);
if ((Ra.top - P) <= 0) {
if ((Ra.top - P) <= R) {
  b.className = 'stop';
  b.style.top = - R +'px';
  b.style.left = 0;
} else {
  b.className = 'sticky';
  b.style.top = P + 'px';
  b.style.left = Ra.left + 'px';
}
} else {
b.className = '';
b.style.top = '';
b.style.left = '';
}
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, '').width;
b.style.left = (b.className == 'sticky' ? (a.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px') : '0');
}, false);
}
})
</script>
```

Источник:[Шпаргалкаблог](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/09/scroll-block.html)

При изменение окна браузера все работает хорошо, плавающие блоки перестраиваются (изменяется ширина - она в %). Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно сделать чтобы все работало точно также, но при изменении ширины определенного блока (например: #layout). А при определенной ширине этого же блока выполнение скрипта прекращалось.

Нашел скрипт для отслеживания ширины одного блока и добавления при её изменении класса к другому блоку.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
function checkWidth() {
var windowWidth = $('article').innerWidth(),
    elem = $("#controller_wrap"); // лучше сохранять объект в переменную, многократно чтобы не насиловать 
                                // страницу для поиска нужного элемента
if(windowWidth < 769){
  elem.removeClass('col-two');
  elem.addClass('col-one');
}
else{
  elem.removeClass('col-one');
  elem.addClass('col-two');
}
}
 checkWidth(); // проверит при загрузке страницы

$(window).resize(function(){
checkWidth(); // проверит при изменении размера окна клиента
});
});
</script>
```

Логика немного схожа, пытался их подружить, но оказалось я плохой "подружитель"

Спасибо за внимание.

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Comment: Теоретически можно использовать фрейм- поместить его в блок, растянуть на всю ширину блока, а потом уже добавить к window фрейма обычный onresize

Comment: Во всяком случае, это буде менее жрущий ресурсы подход, чем просто проверять ширину-высоту блока каждые 100мс

Comment: Михаил, я дополнил вопрос. Как Вы думаете, может быть что-то подобное нужно добавить в первом скрипте? Разве нельзя проверять ширину-высоту блока не каждые 100мс, а непосредственно только при изменение ширины блока.

Comment: А.. Ну так пример с фреймами- это "на все случаи жизни", то-есть, если размер блока будет изменяться без ресайза окна. А так- конечно, то, чем вы дополнили уже является решением

Comment: Только там немного переписать нужно, чтоб "не насиловать страницу".. Вроде наоборот же, многократное объявление переменной + ещё получение элемента даёт большую нагрузку

Comment: "...если размер блока будет изменяться без ресайза окна". То есть если размер блока будет изменяться без ресайза окна, то решение  без фрейма будет ресурсопотребляемым? Михаил, а можете Вы мне (не удаляя свой ответ ниже) показать как это решить без фрейма, и объяснить в двух слова насколько это плохо (сильно) повлияет на производительность сайта пожалуйста.

Comment: Простите, я не особо специалист, но попытаюсь объяснить; Дело в том, что тогда вам придётся через какой-либо интервал проверять размер блока и сравнивать его с прошлым размером. А самое нехорошее, что в отличии от onresize такая функция будет выполняться постоянно, даже если пользователь ничего там не делает. Да и криво это будет выглядеть. Вот представьте, вы что-то растягиваете, а оно переходит рывками.

Comment: Спасибо, Михаил, в общих чертах с этим все ясно. Надеюсь Вы не против, если я объясню причину возникновения своего первого, выше заданного вопроса. На сайте имеется слайд-панель выезжающая слева. У этой панели имеется чекбокс, при клике на который панель фиксируется, и весь основной контент странице смещается вправо на расстояние равной ширине панели. По клику  на чекбокс происходит присвоение класса определенному элементу с запоминанием в локальном хранилище, через который и происходит управление положением блока с контентом и слайд-панелью.

Comment: Именно в момент фиксирования панели (и наоборот),  когда происходит  смещение контента (с запоминанием, без перезагрузки страницы), только эти плавающие блоки подгоняются под новую ширину блока с контентом после ресайза окна или перезагрузки страницы. Так возможно ли тогда при клике на чекбокс сохранить значение в хранилище и параллельно перезагрузить страницу.

Comment: Чекбокс заменен ссылкой 
<a class="p-fix" onclick="onclickSpanel();javascript: location.reload(true);"></a> Работает так как нужно, но при клики перед обновлением страницы страницы пользователь успевает увидеть смещение а соответственно и эти "болтающийся" не на своем месте блоки. Наверняка это легко решается через CSS, увелечением задержки анимации. Но мне интересно, с точки зрения кодинга насколько это решение (повесить два события на одну ссылку) правильное, и чем может быть чревато.

Comment: Да в принципе ничем не чревато... Вот только как вы в онклик поместили javascript:....

Comment: Так можно при клике по ссылке только сохранять значение true false в хранилище, а уже при загрузке страницы выполнять функцию, которая фиксирование панели

Comment: Исправил на <a class="p-fix" onclick="onclickSpanel();location.reload(true);"></a>.  Забавно, но с javascript тоже работало, почему так?

Comment: Можно поподробнее пожалуйста! У меня вот что обрабатывает клик                                                                                                    <script>
var slidPanel = document.getElementById('p_prldr');

function onclickSpanel() {
  slidPanel.className = (slidPanel.className == 'fix-panel') ? '' : 'fix-panel';
  localStorage.setItem('hide', slidPanel.className); // сохраняем значение в ключ hide
}

if(localStorage.getItem('hide') == 'fix-panel') { // если значение ключа hide "fix-panel"
  document.getElementById('p_prldr').className = 'fix-panel';
}
</script>

Comment: С фреймом у меня вообще ничего не выводит. А вот это "при клике по ссылке только сохранять значение true false в хранилище, а уже при загрузке страницы выполнять функцию, которая фиксирование панели" судя по всему как раз то что в данном случае меня выручит. Михаил помогите, пожалуйста все это правильно оформить.

Comment: Точно не знаю, что у вас отвечает за фиксацию панели, поэтому будет panFix(arg), которая фиксирует, если arg=true и скрывает, если arg=false. Да в принципе всё дальше просто... При нажатии на ссылку выполнять localStorage.setItem(!localStorage.getItem('val')), а при загрузке страницы panFix(!!localStorage.getItem('val'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

увы, здесь нельзя использовать фреймы, поэтому вот код:

```
HTML
<div id="block">
<iframe id="fr" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>


JS
document.querySelector("#fr").contentWindow.addEventListener("resize",function(){
  //тут любые функции
})
```

рабочий пример на codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/goGqvm?editors=1111

Comment: Михаил, спасибо Вам за помощь! Добавил проверку значения ключа только при загрузке страницы, Теперь почти идеально... Наверное с фреймом это выглядело бы намного лучше визуально и не только (да и без лишней перезагрузки), но в моем случае весь контент помещенный во фрейм (а это почти вся страница, исключение: шапка, подвал и панель), имеет множество динамических элементов, что поведет за собой ряд дополнительных проблем. Уверен, что ответ выше решает мою проблему , исключи я часть динамических элементов, Но я пошел другим путем, в котором Вы же мне опять и помогли. Спасибо!

Comment: Можно галочку на ответе?)

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Да, конечно! Уже )